# Fork a git repo, then push some commits upstream (but not all)

Tags: git, github

I have forked a public github repo. I am making some commits that I plan to keep in my local fork, because they don't belong in the original community version.
However, as I work I'm finding that I actually do want to push some of my commits to the community version.

What is the correct way to handle this?  Should I branch my fork for my own personal work, but keep the changes that belong upstream in the master branch of my fork?

Thanks community!

Comment: There is no such things as pushing _changes_. You push a _commit_. Typically, that commit is a _branch_. So, make a branch that expresses the state you want the original repo to be in. You would then communicate that branch to the owners of the original repo in whatever way they prefer (e.g. pull request).

Comment: Your idea for a solution seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Matt - edited question to match with your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a branch from a *clean* master and [cherry pick](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick) the commits you want into that branch. Then submit that branch as a pull request.

Because you've made changes to master, **do not make your branch from your master**. If you do, your pull request will contain other commits you've made locally. Any branch you plan to submit must be branched from the upstream master. Add the upstream as a remote, then branch from the upstream master.

```
git remote add upstream <upstream url>
git fetch upstream
git branch yourbranch upstream/master
```

(I advise not making any commits to master, or any upstream branch, in a forked repository. Instead, exclusively commit to your own branches. This avoids sending a pull request based off a master with local changes.)